# React Loadable (Lazy load) on 'load'?

Tags: reactjs, lazy-loading, react-lazy-load

I am very impressed with react loadable library here: https://github.com/jamiebuilds/react-loadable

But I am confused if this is beneficial if I use this on `load` (by calling `setState` after load event)

On all the examples/blogs I have read, everywhere it's calling on CTA click.

So the question is, should I dynamic import components on '`load`' event and will it improve my page performance?

My concern is with lighthouse score of my react app.

Thanks

Comment: React has built in feature. Check https://reactjs.org/docs/concurrent-mode-suspense.html

Comment: Thanks @demkovych, but the limitation is, in production, we are using "react": "16.4.2", which does not supports react lazy nor suspense.